# SendWait and Variable

Tags: powershell

I am sending keys in IE automation process. First I press Ctrl+S (Save), then I want to save WebPage as MHT file named as variable `$currentDate`.

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^{s}')
Start-Sleep -m 500
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{$currentDate}')
```

What is the correct format of usage variable in `SendWait('{}')`?

I've tried both `('{'"$currentDate"'}')` and `('{"$currentDate"}')`

Comment: why do you use send keys? Use the save as command from theInternetExplorer.Application object

Answer (score 2):

Read and follow [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1) article:

> When you enclose a string in **double quotation marks** (a
>   double-quoted string), variable names that are preceded by a dollar
>   sign (`$`) are replaced with the variable's value before the string is
>   passed to the command for processing.
>
> …
>
> When you enclose a string in **single-quotation marks** (a
>   single-quoted string), the string is passed to the command exactly as
>   you type it. **No substitution is performed**.

**Example**:

```
$currentdate = (get-date).ToString('yyyyMMdd-HHmm')
$currentdate
"$currentdate"
'$currentdate'
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("SendWait=$currentdate")
```

**Output** in an open `Powershell` prompt:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\47649742.ps1
20171205-1454
20171205-1454
$currentdate
PS D:\PShell> SendWait=20171205-1454
```